# how can we change the button size in java code

Tags: android, button

I created the button in java code and i cant change the size of the button.I used

```
            btn = new Button(Activity.this);
    btn.setText("\t\t" + lbl + "\t\t\t  ");
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button);
    btn.setwidth(100);
```

but no use.Any idea?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 btn = new Button(Activity.this);
btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    btn.setText("\t\t" + lbl + "\t\t\t  ");
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_button);
    btn.setwidth(100);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
btn.getLayoutParams().width=300;
btn.getLayoutParams().height=100;
```

This will set your button width `300px` button height`100px`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//converting dps to pixels dip-pixel
//username refers to edittext in the main UI thread
```

You need

```
Resources r = getResources();
int px =(int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP
                                  ,200
                                  ,r.DisplayMetrics()); 
username.setWidth(px);
```

you need to convert device pixels into pixels to set the width. Here, 200 is the width of edittext UI widget in dp.

[Watch this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJPhexlBOiw)